# How to reduce the number of triggered mousewheel scroll events in a time interval to a single event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently in my site, I have a mousewheel function that scrolls the user to set positions on the page. This function, however, triggers multiple times when users scroll somewhat quickly and don't limit their scrolling to a single unit of mousewheel scroll. How do I take all the mousewheel scroll events in a certain time interval of lets say one second and make that trigger my function a single time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [debouncing](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/) on your event handler.  [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) / [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) provide debounce functionality, but jQuery does not.  A simple example taken from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) looks like this:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Once you have this available, you can use it like this:

```
var delay = 1000; // 1s

var handlerFunction = debounce(function (e) {
  console.log(1);
}, delay);

$(document).on('scroll', handlerFunction);
```

And your handler will only actually *execute* 1000ms after the last time the handler is called.

[JSBIN here](http://jsbin.com/zolopavoyo/edit?js,console,output) for you to play with.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery code lets you set an interval in milliseconds.

```js
var intervalMs = 2000;

var last = 0;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  if (last + intervalMs < now) {
    last = now;
    
    // do stuff
  }
});
```